How do I fix the android studio colorbuffer error code 4300000000 when running emulator?
So I am getting this error when I try running the android studio emulator:
FATAL in initVkEmulationFeatures, err code: 4300000000: Failed to find memory type for ColorBuffers.

I tried freeing up space and reinstalling android studio multiple times. I get the same error every time. For clarity, I am on a windows computer and setting up the environment for react native. How do I fix this problem?



Switch Graphics Rendering Engine
Try switching the graphics rendering engine of the emulator to Software instead of using the default GPU setting.

Open Android Studio.
Go to AVD Manager.
Select your emulator and click on the Edit (pencil) icon.
Click on Show Advanced Settings.
Under Graphics, select Software.
Click Finish and then try running the emulator again.

Disable Vulkan Support
Disabling Vulkan support might resolve the issue since it's related to Vulkan emulation.

Open Android Studio.
Go to AVD Manager.
Select your emulator and click on the Edit (pencil) icon.
Click on Show Advanced Settings.
Scroll down to Emulated Performance and select Hardware - GLES 2.0.
Click Finish and then try running the emulator again.

Update Graphics Drivers
Ensure your graphics drivers are up to date:

Go to the AMD website or the website of your graphics card manufacturer.
Download and install the latest drivers for your AMD Radeon R4 Graphics.
Restart your computer and try running the emulator again.

Allocate More RAM to the Emulator
Sometimes allocating more RAM to the emulator can help:

Open Android Studio.
Go to AVD Manager.
Select your emulator and click on the Edit (pencil) icon.
Click on Show Advanced Settings.
Increase the Memory allocation.
Click Finish and try running the emulator again.
Try this solution, hope this will help you.
